# mysql random number selection error from a table

Tags: php, mysql

i have a query that runs well on my localhost mysql server, but when i run it on my php script as a query, gets the "random_number" as the query error. I want to select a random     number from 0 to 50 that is not existing in my seat_number table.
    here is my query:
    Does anyone have any ideas?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 50) + 0  AS random_number
FROM seat_number WHERE "random_number" NOT IN (SELECT Seatno FROM seat_number) ");
while($row5 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $numQuestion = $row5['random_number'];
       }
```

I have tried with and without "" around random_number, but isn't working.
Any ideas guys?

Comment: Do you have any ideas? Quotes maybe?

Comment: You can tell by the way you pasted your query that you have an issue with the quotes.

Comment: Side note: beware that `mysql_query()` has been deprecated for years, will trigger deprecated notices in PHP/5.5 and PHP/5.6 and will likely be removed in some future releases.

Comment: Even if i remove the mysql_query(), it results in the same way, errors

Answer (score 0):

try something like this using `not exist`:

```
   SET @rand = FLOOR(RAND() * 50) + 0;
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT @rand) AS random_number
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT Seatno FROM seat_number
      WHERE seat_number = @rand);
```

Comment: Tried, not working too, its becoz the random_number is recognized, when i ran it on mysql db, i added "" to it: "random_number" and it returned data, but in php script , it fails.

Comment: i'm running it this way:   
$result= mysql_query("SET @rand = FLOOR(RAND() * 50) + 0;
  SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT @rand) AS random_number
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT Seatno FROM seat_number
      WHERE seat_number = = @rand"); but not working

Comment: not working either :(   $result= mysql_query(" SET @rand = FLOOR(RAND() * 50) + 0; SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT @rand) AS random_number
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT Seatno FROM seat_number
      WHERE seat_number = @rand");
  while($row5 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $random1 = $row5['random_number'];
    }

Comment: $result= mysql_query(" SET @rand = FLOOR(RAND() * 50) + 0; SELECT * FROM (SELECT @rand) AS random_number WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Seatno FROM seat_number WHERE seat_number = @rand)"); while($row5 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ $random1 = $row5['random_number']; }

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, double quotes are used to quote identifiers (tables, columns...) but MySQL has a strange way to adhere to the standard:

- By default, it simple ignores it and uses double quotes for string literals
- There's a setting you can change and make it behave as in the standard

You're apparently using two servers that have different double-quote semantics.

The setting you need to change is [sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html), more specifically the [ANSI_QUOTES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) value. Thankfully, `sql_mode` can be changed at session scope.